# Newly created items are not added to the solution until I close and reopen it (VS2017)

Tags: visual-studio-2017

This is slowly driving me crazy.  It is a problem I did not have with VS2015 and only showed up when I started using VS2017.  I have upgraded to the first service pack and that did not change anything.

It is a C# .NET Core project if that matters.  Any time I create a new file (e.g. Foo.cs) it doesn't seem to get associated with the solution.  If I try and reference it from an existing file then the IDE doesn't recognize it and it reports an error.  Any open tabs I have with these files shows them as "Miscellaneous files" where it would normally have "ProjectName(netcoreapp1.1)".

If I close the solution and then reopen it then everything works fine.  Building or rebuilding the solution does not fix the issue.  Is anyone else seeing this problem?

Comment: It looks like your csproj file is not updatesd/saved until you close the solution

Comment: Can you try running VS as administrator. I've had similar issues because it has to edit the csproj and it does not have permission to do so.

Comment: @MindingData I tried that, it did not work but you still may be on to something.  Now that I'm explicitly testing I find this behavior actually happens only some of the time.  Other times the file is added to the csproj correctly.  It seems possible there could be a write conflict to the file at times that isn't present at others.

Comment: Honestly I've had this exact same issue before. For example adding a class to a class library and trying to reference that namespace and it not working. I was a contractor and working on a machine that was super locked down. Similar to you I could restart VS and add the file to the project and everything would work as per normal. It is frustrating!